# Combining Ascension expansions: tokens and boards

Tags: deck-building, ascension

The original Ascension (CoTG) includes 50 tokens/beads and is playable by 4 people. Expansions such as Immortal Heroes include 30 more tokens, allowing for up to 6 players. Storm of Souls is said to be a complete game for up to 4 players, including a new board and 50 more tokens.

My questions are:

1. is it possible to group two expansions and play with 8 people, or that's just too crazy / impossible?
2. buying two expansions, can I simply trash the additional tokens and keep a number around 80 for the 6 players? On average it seems 50 tokens/4 players would turn into 75/6 players, but I'm unsure if token rules change.
3. Do I need the new board from Storm of Souls or can I keep the original one? It seems it has a space for the new Event cards, but little besides that - unsure, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion:

1. I don't think there are any any interactions between sets to-date that would make this *impermissible*, but this *might* be inadvisable.  Consider that cards with set-specific interactions will become more ineffective as you combine sets with different mechanics (as the odds of useful interactions decreases, the value of those cards decrease).
2. Sure, but less tokens-per-player will presumably mean less cards and turns-per-player, so decks that excel in the short-term will win more often than decks that take a while to build out. I'm thinking "kill-the-monsters" type decks will be favored over "invest in the longer term"-type decks.
3. All of the Ascension games that I'm aware of can be played without boards altogether - they just suggest a physical layout for different types of cards.

Comment: I strongly agree with point 1 as with the ios app I will play with all expansions enabled and can get turns where I play my entire deck (plus all cards purchased that turn) and get 100+ purchase and fight on the turn so can quickly get a lot of power.

Answer (score 0):

1. Combining two base sets is totally possible (I've done it multiple times), going up to 8 is a little odd but should be possible. The downtime will then significantly increase and can lead to boredom while waiting for your turn and I don't really see how the game benefits from such a large group.
2. The tokens have different value and this is very important. The game states in the small expansions that you should include 30 points worth of per player regardless of player size, so you are able to ditch everything but 5 white ones and 5 red ones per player and a couple of red ones for once the base pool runs out but play finishes the round. I've bought 3 base sets and 3 small expansions and have given most of the gems to my daughter to play with.
3. As said by others, the board is absolutely unnecessary. You can just put 6 open cards to buy/fight, the cultist, mystics and heavy infantry in a stack each, the current event card as the top of the event discard pile, the event draw deck and the draw and discard pile for the buy/fight cards anywhere on the table and are good to go. Dominion and Thunderstone do it that way and those work very well too.